# Augmented Reality Frameworks for Android App Development

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I have been looking for an up-to-date answer to the question:
What is the recommended AR Framework to use for Android App development?

I want to start to learn AR so a framework with tutorials, community, etc... is preferable. So far the 2 that popped out are: **Vuforia** (Free version / License) and **ARToolkit** (Open-Source).

While looking I didn't find a lot of content for developing in Android Studio, why is that? There's plenty of Unity + *Framework X* content, but none for Android Studio.

Looking for people to shed some light on this and share his/her experience developping AR apps.

Thanks already

Comment: Have you done any research on Augmented Reality. Did you find Tango (was called Project Tango) which is done with extra sensor not found in regular devices. Which tool is geared toward modeling 3d objects?

Comment: Project Tango does indeed need Tango-supported phones, like Lenovo Phab. I am looking for something that will support the current generation of phones.

Comment: To answer your question regarding why most content you see on this regards is not for Android Studio - this is because Unity is easier. Many people prefer doing less programming (because they want to save time, or because their skills require this, and because it is enough for their needs). Programming Vuforia via pure OpenGL ES, even in Java, requires more effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before it was Metaio, but it was bought by apple. I used for many years and it was ok but it is not available anymore for Android.

Aside from what you mentioned there is also Wikitude SDK and DroidAR: 
[Wikitude SDK](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/androidnative/)

[DroidAR](http://bitstars.github.io/droidar/)

There might be more but so far I haven't heard. It is also worth tracking the future development of Vulkan Api.

[Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/)

Comment: DroidAR seems interesting but the git repo hasn't been updated for some years now. 

I think I'm going to give Wikitude trial a try, maybe in combination with Xamarin, since they also support that.